# How to pass service pointers from one package to another package in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, pass-by-reference

I separated different `http.HandleFunc` in different files according to which page they are related to. I use `gorilla/sessions` to manage client sessions and user authentication and I use `go-sql-driver` for accessing a MySQL database.

Project Layout:

```
<PROJECT ROOT>
   -> <cliend>                     // This folder containing html, css, and js
   -> <pagehndler>
         -> <index>
                -> index.go        // Need to access database and session 
         -> <projbrwsr>
                -> projbrwsr.go    // Need to access database and session
   -> main.go
```

Therefore, I have 1 pointer pointing to the `go-sql-driver` service

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")
```

and 1 pointer pointing to `gorilla/sessions` service

```
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("something-very-secret"))
```

There are 2 methods to pass the two pointers to other packages in my understanding:

1. Wrap the two pointers into two packages (`sess`, `db`) and make them exported. And, the package that requires the service needed to import the packages (`sess`, `db`). And call the exported pointers.

   ```
   <PROJECT ROOT>
      -> <cliend>                     // This folder containing html, css, and js
      -> <pagehndler>
            -> <index>
                   -> index.go        // Need to access database and session 
            -> <projbrwsr>
                   -> projbrwsr.go    // Need to access database and session
      -> <service>
             -> sess.go               // Storing the database service pointer
             -> db.go                 // Storing the session service pointer
      -> main.go
   ```
2. Initialize the two pointers in main package and pass them to the another package, that contain the page handle functions, as args. Inside the another package, set the args to a local variable so we can call it locally in the another package.

   ```
    <PROJECT ROOT>
       -> <cliend>                     // This folder containing html, css, and js
       -> <pagehndler>
             -> <index>
                    -> index.go        // Need to access database and session
                                       // Containing a func newService(db *DB)
             -> <projbrwsr>
                    -> projbrwsr.go    // Need to access database and session
                                       // Containing a func newService(sess *CookieStore)
       -> main.go
   ```

What is the best way to pass this two pointers to other packages for other handle function to call them?

Comment: If the variables are exported (i.e., begin with an uppercase letter), you can access them from any package by qualifying with the package name. Since you're talking about "wrapping the pointers into two packages", does that mean that they aren't in separate packages now? Can you explain more about how your code is organized?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my post.

Comment: i prefer to explicitly pass dependencies across the package boundary into a constructor function. i'm actually right now refactoring a project from method 1 to method 2, [here's my wip](https://github.com/namely/broadway/pull/121/files#diff-1427b112aa72f64adcf839007e954d56R18) where I define a shared `cfg.Type` and pass it from my cmd package to server package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the concept which should work.

Inside the package you should declare a variable, which is exported. This variable has to be a pointer.

```
var myVar = 3
var MyPointer = &myVar
```

https://play.golang.org/p/EQDwGF7pjv

From your main package you can set the pointer to your "global" db or session adress.

```
mypackage.MyPointer = dbPointer
```

Then the pointer inside your package points to your dbPointer. I think this is a good way to pass a pointer into other packages.

Comment: This method seems like in javascript. We can create and assign a value to a package externally. Right?

Comment: Yes and no. You can not create a variable, but you can assign a value to it. Another possibility would be to pass a variable to all functions of your package.

Comment: Pass a variable to all functions by "args"?

Comment: Yes. Would be the functional way. If you need a db reference inside of a function, why should you not pass the reference with one argument? Easier to test easier to understand, specially if your package is huge.